# Auto update jtable? Timer or Concurrency?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am planning to deploy an application with a jtable in it to several machines connected to a server with my MySQL Database. The database will feed the jtable from the app. What I want to do is any of the user won't need to refresh their application everytime someone from other machine will make changes with the database. Should I use Timer? For example I will make a scheduled task that will refresh the table every 1 second for example.

It will be very helpful if you will provide how to implement both but any answer will be accepted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend a quick fetch of a single row single column (there may be many metrics with this) for a `lastUpdt` being a `DATETIME`. Compare that to your app's var for its last fetch. That will be your `isDirty` flag. Only fetch the data for a refresh if `isDirty`. Determine your time interval for doing the first part of what I said (say, every 20 seconds)

Comment: I find it hard to implement this. I'm sorry I'm just a noob but thanks for your input anyway! Much appreciated.

Comment: What might you find easier :p

Comment: Haha I do hope I'll find something easier. But is there anyway to set a timer then just call my 'feedTable' method?